# Is there a constant $C$ such that $\prod_{p\leq x}\dfrac{p-1}{p}<\dfrac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log x}\cdot C$?

Tags: prime-numbers, products

By Mertens' third theorem:
$$\prod_{p\leq x}\dfrac{p-1}{p}\sim\dfrac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log x}$$
But does there exist a constant $C$ such that:
$$\prod_{p\leq x}\dfrac{p-1}{p}<\dfrac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log x}\cdot C$$
Or otherwise, does there exist a (hopefully very small) constant $C$ for which:
$$\prod_{p\leq x}\dfrac{p-1}{p}<\dfrac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log x}+ C$$
The only (trivial) thing I've found so far is:
$$\prod_{p\leq x}\dfrac{p-1}{p}<\dfrac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log x}+ 0.5$$

Oh and if the constant exists, what is it's value? That's the main thing I would like to know.

Comment: $f(x) \sim g(x)$ when $x \to \infty$ means that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 1$ when $x \to \infty$. hence obviously yes for the multiplicative constant $C$, and yes for the additive constant too, because the RHS $\to 0$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the thing I'm really interested in is the value of the constant.

Comment: I can't see how you can really be interested in those if you didn't study the Riemann zeta function, nor the prime number theorem.

Comment: Well I need them for calculating an upper bound for $\sum_{2>p\geq\sqrt{2x}}\prod_{2>q\geq p}\dfrac{q-2}{q}$

Comment: what don't you understand with $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= 1$ ?

Comment: I think I understand now that the constants exist, but I need their values for the reason I explained in my other comment.

Comment: if you are wondering "what is the value of $C$" it means that you didn't understand

Comment: well okay, then I didn't understand it. I would like to, tough.And isn't it possible that $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is already close to $1$ for small $x$?

Comment: why would you care when $x$ is small ? $x$ will anyway become large at some time

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here. If there exists a constant, doesn't it have a value? or is it infinite?

Comment: I recommend you to start by noticing that $\prod_{p \le x} \frac{p-1}{p} = \prod_{p \le x} (1-1/p)$ which  clearly decreases when $x$ increases. the  [Mertens theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems) says that it decreases as $\frac{\alpha}{\log x}$ (this is in fact the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem))  and gives a precision on the constant $\alpha = e^{-\gamma}$

Comment: Okay, I understand that, But I still don't get what you want me to understand about $C$. I've done some testing and it looks like the RHS is already larger for finite values of $x$, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: @Mastrem See theorem $6.12$ of http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1002/1002.0442v1.pdf .

Comment: @Marco Cantarini Thanks! That was exactly what I needed. I got one question though. Does $log^2$ just mean the same as $log_2$?

Comment: @Mastrem No, it means $(\log(x))^{2}$.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot